# Split database per pool

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to split a database of users...

Comment: Sounds like a good way to make a simple structure far more complex. What are you wanting to acheive? Are you solving a performance problem? If so which one?

Comment: @danblack it's not about performance, it's for a survey. The company wanna I split per ESP and others criteria

Comment: Do you really need to split the data in your database? Or do you just need to be able to query data by different segments?  Do the segments need to have any logical commonality? Or could it be random? The Mod operator is commonly used to do this sort of queue segmentation

Comment: @AMtwo About the split, I will create the new columns named Pool_ESP and with data like A, B, C... I need to have a history of action we will do on each pool, example we send message type 1 to pool B, type 2 to pool C...
About distro it can be randomly but by ESP (like above) the goal it is to respect the criteria of balancing (here per ESP and per number of pool they will ask me)

Comment: What is "ESP"?  What do you mean by "pool".

Comment: I'll bet you that the biggest 20% of the users occupy 80% of the capacity.  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle )  So, an even split, or even a random split, won't necessarily help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody looking something for solve the similare issue look for by the side of

```
MySQL NTILE()
```

You can split database on equal part based on a column value.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_ntile

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a pretty common concept in Customer Relationship Management (CRM) systems and other marketing software. It's common to break up an audience into *segments* using various criteria--most software basically provides a query builder of sorts where you use a query to define the audience. In a marketing campaign, different segments get different materials and messaging based on some criteria--for example, in a direct email campaign, household income might determine which car model an auto maker markets, or how large of a donation a nonprofit ask for. The process of selecting your audience and sub-audiences is known as **segmentation**.

What segment you are in is not an attribute of the individual, but of the marketing campaign or event. In your case, it sounds like instead of marketing campaigns, you're doing surveys. Based on how a Marketing CRM handles this, your data relationship/hierarchy would look something like this:

- People / customers
- Surveys
- Campaigns / survey groups

  - Criteria / query used to identify the full audience (which might be "the same people in prior survey x")
  - Criteria / queries used to segment the full audience into smaller segments.
  - List of customers/people who are in the full audience, plus the segments they belong in. This is often saved as a snapshot that gets cached/recached to help you evaluate if your segmentation rules/queries are correct.

    - Mapping of which surveys get sent to which segments & when
    - Mapping of which people received which survey

Essentially, each of those bullets is a separate table, and the indentation identifies the parent-child relationship. It's important to note that the design of Marketing CRMs is such that it's specifically designed to have people broken into segments, and each segment gets a consistent set of communication within that segment, while different segments get different communication, and who gets what is carefully tracked for analytics later. Future campaigns may get segmented differently as business requirements change, or as you learn from how successful prior campaigns are.

In your case, you're building a CRM for a specific purpose. Don't re invent the wheel. Learn from how other CRMs are built. You may even want to research the *marketing/business side of things* to understand how they handle segmentation, so that you can design your schema to meet those business requirements of your users

Comment: The company have lot of tools, just marketing service don't know how to use it and I can't tell them RTFM ! !

Comment: By the thx for your reply, he give me some answers.